# Using Angular's ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking at [Mastering Web Application Development in Angular](http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book), I tried to use the `ng-if` Directive to not show a `<div>` if an expression was `false`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-if="showSecret">Secret</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {  
    $scope.showSecret = (function() { 
        return false;
    })();
}
```

But, looking at this JsFiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/64GCp/2/), I see that `Secret` gets rendered. Why?

Comment: Use ngShow or ngHide instead

Comment: The book says: `The ng-show/ng-hide directives are easy to use but might have unpleasant performance consequences if applied to large number of DOM nodes`

Comment: I was trying to remove my `-1` (before I saw you deleted your answer) as you said you had used `ng-show`/`ng-hide` numerous times. But, if you could please elaborate on why `ng-if` is wrong, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using v1.0.1 and documentation [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/docs-1.0.1/api) doesn't show an `ngIf` document.

The first instance of it I see is [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) in version 1.2.0

Changing the library version works: http://jsfiddle.net/64GCp/4/

Answer (score 0):

The options to hide and show are `ng-show` or `ng-hide` and later in version Angularjs 1.2.0+ `ngIf`

http://jsfiddle.net/64GCp/3/

All directives are  executed over the DOM and therefore both **ngShow** or **ngIf** will be executed equally.

I have personally used **ngShow** in a page a large number of times(I decided to used "large number" to highlight the ambiguity) and tested it in all browsers including IE8 with no problems at all.

What the book is probably referring to is that the size of the page will not change because all ngShow/ngHide does is to hide the element:

**ng-show output**

```
  <div ng-show="showSecret" style="display: none;">Secret</div>
```

While ngIf only leaves a comment:

**ng-if output**

```
  <!-- ngIf: checked -->
```

**Important:** the first stable version to add ng-if was angular 1.2.0 make sure you have this version or higher before planning to use it.

Please understand 2 things, Angular is rapidly changing framework and so are the browsers it is always a good practice to search for benchmarks/versions to confirm or discard features. It is also possible that the internal functionality of directives may change overtime. For instance Angular Team announced that they dropped IE8 support in version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The version of angular you are using does not support ng-if. Use a newer version. See my fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/SdYH5/